# I have two html files with the same background image. When I display them side to side, I need them to have a common background image

Tags: html, css

When I want to display the HTML's side by side, I am using UI regions to specify left half to display one html and right half to display the second html. But since both of them have the same background image, the same image is appearing in left and right sides of screen. Any way I can make the same image as common background for both while displaying side by side. Any way I can put a plain html file with background image below, set transparency of bg image of both files to 1 and display them on top of the plain html? Please help.

Comment: You could use background-position in CSS, on 1 screen aligned left and on the other align right. If you use a background, twice the size of 1 normal background. They should form 1 full width background together. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-position

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an element around both sections and put the background in that.